# In Rails the file_field helper is not allowing multiple selections to appear in params hash returned to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filefield

I have a multiple select dialog that is only returning one file to the controller in the params hash when multiple files are selected.

Rails 5.0.1

```
<%= form_for(@out_transfer) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :pdf, multiple: true, accept: 'application/pdf', name: 'pdf' %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit("Send PDF's", class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
  </div>
<% end %>

  def create
    params['pdf'].original_filename
  end
```

The params only shows the last file selected.  Please take a look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It needs an array, try the following:

```
<%= f.file_field :pdf, multiple: true, accept: 'application/pdf', name: 'pdf[]' %>
```

Notice the square brackets `[]`